# Give angles to images in circular slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a circular image slider. When a user clicks on any images it slides into center. On the left side images I want to to add in class to give some angle, and right side image I want to add in different class to give different angle.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
    var t=$(this);
    t.prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
    t.nextAll().removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.t1
{
    transform: skewX(5deg) skewY(175deg); /* W3C */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(5deg) skewY(175deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
    -moz-transform: skewX(5deg) skewY(160deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: skewX(5deg) skewY(175deg); /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-transform: skewX(5deg) skewY(175deg); /* Opera */
}

.t2
{
    transform: skewX(-5deg) skewY(15deg); /* W3C */
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-5deg) skewY(10deg); /* Safari & Chrome */
    -moz-transform: skewX(-5deg) skewY(5deg); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: skewX(-5deg) skewY(10deg); /* Internet Explorer */
    -o-tran
}
```

On click event of image I am giving angle, but on click of last '12th' images will not show correct alignement because previous all will go in same class, how to do it?

[image]

Comment: please replicate your problem on jsbin.com.

Comment: in jsfiddle and bin its not working , cause it has so many files

Comment: We'll need to see more code than this to help though..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, perspective seems not to be supported yet (at least in chrome where I tested it).

But you can use other transformations, just use the css attribute `transform` (or the prefixed ones):

```
img {
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg, 5deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 5deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 5deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 5deg);
}
```

Check out this example (tested in chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/uynXh/5/